# .desktop WINE — open file in running program

Tags: 18.04, wine, .desktop

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I'm running a text editor under WINE and am trying to figure how to add the ability to right-click on a text file in a file manager and have it open in that text editor, or at least make it part of the options.

I already have the following to start the editor:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=NoteTab Pro
Comment=Create and edit text files
Exec=wine "/home/lee/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/NoteTab 7/NotePro.exe"
Type=Application
MimeType=text/css;text/csv;text/html;text/plain;
```

I couldn't find an existing answer; if there is one, point the way!

Comment: I am on Kubuntu but they are similar enough.  Right click on the file and select properties.  Then File Type Options.  Add. Then type notepad(Best if you have Q4 installed).  Add notepad to the list of ways that a .txt file can open. Then save that and try.

Comment: The problem is that the software runs under WINE and is not listed in the right click menu. I am using Double Commander as my file manager but I do have 'Files'.

Comment: Yes.  Totally understand.  You have to add it to the right click menu.  You need to find where file type options are set.  Then add notepad to the options for .txt files.  Then it will appear.